# Automatically duplicate pivot column, but exclude certain values?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a column that I would like to duplicate onto a new sheet. The column can be filtered:

[image: filter menu]

I want to duplicate everything in this column except for the 'Approved' cells (1st option in the drop-down filter menu). This needs to be done automatically, so that if I change data in the column or add new data, the duplicate column instantly reflects the changes. And this has to happen without Macros, because they run too slow on the computers that will run this file.

I've tried a few combinations of index-matching and 'if' statements, but nothing I've tried so far has been effective. I have absolutely no clue how to accomplish this without the use of macros. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Situation 1:** *Old records with **Approved** in Column.*

[image]

**Situation 2:** *New records with **Approved** in Column along with **Copied/Pulled** records.*

[image]

**N.B.**

- `Red Cells` are `Criteria` where `1` is `Column Offset for Col B in Sheet 1` and `Approved` is the `Value to match`.
- With `2nd Screen Shot` **New Records** are in `Green Color`.
- To make the Formula Dynamic I've used `a Cell for the Criteria`.

**How it works:**

- In **Sheet 2** fill cell `A1` with `Column Offset position` and `B1` with Criteria.
- Array Formula in **Sheet 2** Cell `A3`, finish Formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & Fill Down with few extra Rows.

  ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$9, SMALL(IF((INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$9, , $A$1)<>$B$1), MATCH(ROW(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$9), ROW(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$9)), ""), ROWS(A3:$A$3)), COLUMNS($A$1:A1)),"")}
  ```

**Edited:**

`(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$4:$B$9, , $A$1)` becomes,

`INDEX($B$4:$B$9, , 1)` and and returns `B4:B9`.

`(INDEX($B$4:$B$9, , $A$1)<>$B$1)` returns,

`{1;1;0;1;1;0}` for **Situation 1** & for **Situation 2** `{1;1;0;1;1;0;1;0;1}`

which finally returns,

`({Ok;No;Fine;One}<=$B$1)` for **Situation 
1**

and

`({Ok;No;Fine;One;Four;New}<=$B$1)` for **Situation 2**.

The **MATCH** part looks like,,

`IF({1;1;0;1;1;0}, MATCH(ROW($B$4:$B$9), ROW($B$4:$B$9)), "") & IF({1;1;0;1;1;0;1;0;1}, MATCH(ROW($B$4:$B$9), ROW($B$4:$B$9)), "")`

becomes,

`IF({1;1;0;1;1;0}, {1;2;3;4;5;6}, "") & IF({1;1;0;1;1;0;1;0;1}, {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9}, "")`

and returns,

`{1;2;"";4;5;""} & {1;2;"";4;5;"";7;"";9}`

and **SMALL** part returns,

`SMALL({1;2;"";4;5;""},1) & {1;2;"";4;5;"";7;"";9}, 1)` and returns `1`.

**Note**, *for better data management **Indexed Range** `B4:B9` in **Sheet 1**, should be a **Dynamic Named Range** also, which avoids to alter the **Indexed Range,** and expands down as many Rows as there are new entries.
.*

*Follow these steps to create **Dynamic Named Range***.

- Press `Ctrl+F3` to open **Name Manager** dialouge.
- Find & Click **New** Button, you find the below show dialogue.

[image]

- Assign a Name of your choice as I did, the Sample Name is `Mydata`.
- **Copy & Paste** below shown Formula in **Refers To** text box.
  `=OFFSET($B$1,0,0,COUNT($B:$B),1)`
- Finish with **Ok**.

**N.B.**

- Then after you could replace `Sheet1!$B$4:$B$9,` with `Mydata` in above shown main Formula.
- Remember using **Dynamic Named Range** is an **optional part**.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the data to be "compacted" to hide blank cells, there is a trivial solution.  Say your data is in column A of Sheet1, starting in row 2.  In Sheet2!A2, use a formula like:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A2),Sheet1!A2="Approved"),"",Sheet1!A2)
```

Replicate that down the column as far as you might ever need.  This just reproduces the source cell value unless that is either "Approved" or blank, in which case it produces a null.  This will immediately reflect any changes on Sheet1, and any prepopulated cells pointing to unused cells on Sheet1 will appear blank.

If you want to hide the blank cells on Sheet2, that's more complicated.  You can use a filter and deselect blank cells.  However, a filter doesn't update when the sheet is recalculated; you need to force reapplying the filter.

You can do that manually with one keystroke.  The sheet2 data will already be correct, hiding the blank cells is cosmetic.  So that is a potentially trivial solution.

If you need hiding the blank cells to be automatic, that will require VBA.  Trigger running it based on a change in Sheet1 column A, and simply have it reapply the filter.  If your concern is just speed, this shouldn't be an issue.

But if you need the filtering, and need it automated, the formula shown above is a waste.  You might as well just prepopulate Sheet2 with cell references to Sheet1.  Then filter to hide both blank cells and "Approved" cells.  Just reapplying the filter with a macro won't be a demanding task.